# Why is it not printing the time in the correct format?

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime as td

key = td.strptime("22:22:22",'%H:%M:%S')
print(key)
```

Output: `1900-01-01 22:22:22`

Comment: why do you import `datetime` as `td`? There is also a `timedelta` object in that module which can be abbreviated as `td`.

Comment: Changing the name does not help

Comment: datetime object always have year, month, and day. 1900-01-01 is the default value if none were given.

Comment: "*the correct format*"—You did not specify any format to use for printing, so it printed with the default format.

Comment: How can I define the format? I thought I already did: '%H:%M:%S'

Comment: I only want the time, not the date.

Comment: Your "format" is to parse the string as datetime object. Not printing it.

Answer (score 1):

strptime returns a datetime object. As you haven't specified a date you get the default. If you want the time then:

```
from datetime import datetime as td

key = td.strptime("22:22:22",'%H:%M:%S')
print(key.time())
```